# ExtJS TextField after input text not call setValue()

Tags: extjs, textfield, blur, setvalue

When I use Ext.form.TextField to input text, I see that the TextField did not call setValue() after I lose focus from it, so its value is still "undefined". So can anyone help me:

1. Explain why don't ExtJS  force the TextField to call setValue() after we input a text to it and lose focus? Is there any secret behind this TextField's behavior, because IMHO this does not make sense.
2. (More important than the question above ^_^) How can I force TextField to setValue right after I input and lose focus from it, without implementing the 'onBlur' handler?
   Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The `value` you're querying is the config option, and if you didn't set it, it will always be empty. To get current value, use `getValue()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean that, can we make it auto set value to itself after losing focus? Because the flow I want it to run is: losing focus --> setValue() --> validate() --> clearInvalid() (to remove the error style occurred at the previous step)

Comment: Well.. it IS setting the value (and it in fact also runs validation before that). Perhaps if you show us your code and better explain the issue, we could answer better.

Comment: Yeah, it performs the way you want out of the box, so you must be doing something to change the behavior.